# Common lisp Error: the value is not of the expected type number

Tags: common-lisp

i am new to lisp, and have some troubles with my function:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'reduce-our)
    #'(lambda(new-expression)
            (setf expression nil)
              (loop while (not (equal new-expression expression)) do
                        (setf expression new-expression)
                        (setf new-expression (reduce-once-our expression))
                        (if (not (equal 'new-expression 'expression))
                            (format t " ==> ~A Further reductions are impossible.~%"
                             new-expression)
            new-expression))))

(reduce-our '(^ x => x))
```

This thows next error:

```
Error: The value ^ is not of the expected type NUMBER.
```

I thought that lisp is trying to evaluate  my input list in while loop, but

```
(not (equal nil '(^ x => x)))
```

works just fine, and i am sure that my function does the same check. So. i don't understand where and why happens this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the error happens in this function? You should look at the backtrace.

Additionally:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'reduce-our)
   #'(lambda (new-expression)
      ...))
```

is typically written as

```
(defun reduce-our (new-expression)
   ...)
```

Then:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'reduce-our)
  #'(lambda(new-expression)
      (setf expression nil) ...
```

Where is the variable `expression` introduced? It is undeclared. Setting the value does not declare a variable.

Then:

```
while (not (foo ...))
```

is just

```
until (foo ...)
```

And

```
(if (not (foo)) a b)
```

is

```
(if (foo) b a)
```

Also: improve the indentation. The editor in Lisp will do that for you. It increases readability for you and others.

Comment: Or if the implementation of Common Lisp that you're using doesn't come with a built-in editor, I would suggest considering using Emacs or Vim as your editor.  Both come with Lisp pretty-printing functions.  You can also find a Lisp pretty-printer script, written in Lisp, [here](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dorai/scmindent/index.html).